# Enforcing static local IP address with Ubuntu 12.04 and BT Home Hub over wireless

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, static-ip

Been having some trouble following instructions on how to set a static IP address with my Ubuntu server and my new router. Previously I'd connected via Ethernet cable, and that seemed to provide a static address (which I'd set in many many git repos, and don't want to have to change them all now).

Is there a way to set a static address for a wireless connection? Does it involve any direct tinkering with the BT hub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to have 3 IP addresses:

1. Your ISP assigned public IP address for the WAN connection on your router. This IP address may be static or dynamic based on your ISP but you do not get to pick what this IP address is.
2. Your statically assigned IP address for the LAN connection on your router. This will always be static and you can choose this IP address.
3. Your IP address on your computer can either be dynamic or static but must be able to connect to the LAN IP address of your router. If Ubuntu server is using a wired connection and you want to use a static IP address then you would assign it to your wired network interface. If Ubuntu server is using a wireless connection and you want to use a static IP address the. You would assign it to your wireless interface.

If you want a dynamic IP address assign to a computer then you need to have a DHCP server configured and the computer must be on the same collision domain as the DHCP server.

Comment: Thank you. I'm interested in point 2. I've configured the BT Home Hub to always provide that specific device with a static IP address of 192.168.1.14, but when I do _ifconfig_ it remains unchanged. Can you tell me what I have to do on the actual machine itself to enforce this address?

Comment: Configuring the BT Home Hub to always issue the same IP address means you are using DHCP on the Ubuntu server. That is NOT a static IP address. You want to read this information. https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-configuration.html